# List of AWS SNS Push DeliveryFailure event FailureType values

Tags: amazon-web-services, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, amazon-sns

Our platform sends push notifications to iOS and Android applications via AWS SNS.

Each application in SNS has a subscription to a `DeleiveryFailure` topic, and we are using events from it to reconcile subscribers between our DB and AWS SNS endpoints.

Documentation about this event is very small even here. If the Android token has changed, we still need to correctly process. We could simulate an invalid token and get the correct `FailureType`, but simulating a changed token is difficult, and there are possibly other Failure types as well.

Where can I find more information about the list of available `FailureTypes` in this event, with descriptions?